# Create shortcut desktop in jnlp of Oracle Forms

Tags: java, oracle, java-web-start, jnlp, oracleforms

I want to create a shortcut in desktop(Windows) for an application in Oracle Forms using jnlp.

I have a jnlp like this (example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<!-- JNLP File to test webstart with Forms Application -->  
<jnlp spec="1.7+" codebase="https://banner-dev.example.com/forms/java">  
<information>  
<title>Banner (Dev)</title>  
<vendor>Ellucian</vendor>  
<description>Banner (Dev) in WebStart</description>  
</information>  
<security>  
<all-permissions/>  
</security>  
<resources>  
<j2se version="1.7+"/>  
<jar href="frmall.jar"/>  
<jar href="sbanicons.jar"/>  
<jar href="sbannerui.jar"/>  
<jar href="sbanspecial.jar"/>  
<jar href="sbanorep_10_1_2_3.jar"/>  
<jar href="jacob.jar"/>  
<jar href="frmwebutil.jar"/>  
</resources>  
<applet-desc name="Banner (Dev)" main-class="oracle.forms.engine.Main" width="1" height="1">  
    <param name="height" value="750" />  
    <param name="width" value="1040" />  
    <param name="serverURL" value="/forms/lservlet?ifcfs=/forms/frmservlet?ifsessid=WLS_FORMS.formsapp.999&#38;acceptLanguage=en-US&#38;config=bannerDev"/>  
    <param name="serverArgs" value="module=guainit.fmx"/>
    <param name="lookAndFeel" value="Oracle"/>
    <param name="colorScheme" value="blaf"/>
    <param name="logo" value="no"/>
</applet-desc>  
</jnlp>
```

(https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/oracle-forms-11g-and-java-web-start)

That is working correctly.
I posted it on a website to open it when the button is clicked. Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es-ES">
  <head>
    <title>Web Launcher</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> Web Launcher</h1>


<script src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:deployJava.launchWebStartApplication('Launcher.jnlp');"><img src="logo.png" height="64" width="64"/></a>


<script src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>        
    var jnlpFile = "Launcher.jnlp";
    deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButtonEx(jnlpFile);
</script>


  </body>
</html>
```

If I press any of the buttons (I do not know what difference there is between the two) the application opens correctly.

What I want is, if is possible, create a shortcut on the desktop to open it from there.
That is, the web is the installation form.

I mean, the users will connect to the web, press the button, install the jre if they do not have it, and the application is installed or a shortcut is created on the desktop.

I have tried many ways in the jnlp but I am not able to make it work.
Like this

```
<offline-allowed/>
<shortcut online="false">
    <desktop/>
    <menu submenu="Application Launcher">
    </menu>
</shortcut>
```

I've tried with online true and false, with/without offline-allowed,etc but none of the ways has worked.

Can this be done in some way?

Thanks in advance

Edit:
I have this configuration in Java:(always allow creation of shortcuts)
[image]

Comment: Just to understand. Are you running a weblogic server with a FORMS service?. Do you want to access it directly or thru an OHS service? . The shortcut on the windows desktop would normally be a normal shortcut like --  javaws "http://<your weblogic host>:<port>/forms/frmservlet?config=<your frmconfig>"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Forms standalone runtime mode](https://blogs.oracle.com/fusionmiddlewaresupport/using-and-securing-forms-standalone-launcher-fsal-v2) (frmsal.jar), it's much more easier than JNLP if you want to create a desktop shortcut and will avoid you problems with Java JAR security.